ID of this flower

Friend of mine keeps saying it is white amaryllis lily, but I really don't think it is. I find the leaves different and the flowers drooping, which amaryllis lilies don't.
Can anyone confirm its ID?
Edit: Another picture


That looks like a "rain lily", Zephyranthes genus, of which there are a ton of cultivars. I based the ID on the manner in which the buds come off the main stem, the shape of the bulbs and early growth in the pots behind the flowers, and the shape and color of the leaves. The linked page doesn't show many great photos, so google the genus and you'll get loads of photos, some of which closely resemble your plant.
Your friend's not completely wrong - zephyranthes are in the Hippeastrae family, along with hippeastrum (the common amaryllis).
UPDATE
Given the new photo, that may be a crinum, as some species do have multiple buds coming out of the same bulb. See Crinum latifolium for a reference. It shares the same family with zephyranthes (Hippeastrae being subsumed into Amarylidaceae after my original reference was written).

Naww.. I don't agree with rain lily. I have several rain lilies including hybrids. I have never seen multiple flower buds coming up in a single stem as in this case. In rain lilies, single flower stem carry single bud, also I have never seen their leaves this wide. However, if you have any evidence, links of such rain lily, please provide them so I get a chance to consider them.

As noted there are a ton of cultivars, and many other species (most notably, Sprekelia) have been added to  Zephyranthes within the past five years. OTOH, your original photo doesn't actually show multiple stems coming from a single bulb - the flowers obstruct that view. Glad you added a new photo - it more clearly shows the growth habit. To determine if it's a true lily, you need to look at a bulb - is it scaled or not?

"is it scaled...?" - yes

A true lily and not a crinum or any other member of the Amaryllidaceae then. A very interesting plant.

Yes, as per my knowledge, your friend is right the flower shown in the image is a White Lily also scientifically known as (Lilium candidum).
UPDATE
As per the second image uploaded by you, it is visible that this plant could be Crinum latifolium. Because in the previous image, the leaves are covered under the flower, which is not clearly visible.

Nope, flower stem, leaves don't match.
